# In Gradle, how do I specify that my androidTest implementation should depend on the release version of a project module?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write a performance test in Android Studio, by using an InstrumentedTest. I have made a separate module just for my performance test. It depends on the other modules in the project. To make my performance test accurate, I'd like my `performancetest` module to depend on the *release* configurations of the other modules.

For example, if I have these three modules in my project:
 - `:foo`
 - `:bar`
 - `:performancetest`

I want the `ExampleInstrumentedTest` in module `:performancetest` to exercise and measure the *release* versions of `:foo` and `:bar`.

How do I configure this? I'm trying to use:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(path: ':foo', configuration: 'release')
    implementation project(path: ':bar', configuration: 'release')
}
```

but when I sync it, I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':performancetest:androidDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':performancetest:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :foo.
     Required by:
         project :performancetest
      > Project :performancetest declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'release' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :foo.
```

but I *definitely* can build a release version of `:foo`.

How can I declare my `:performancetest` to rely on the *release* versions of `:foo` and `:bar`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.

performancetest.build.gradle

```
android {
    // We want our performance test to run with the _release_ version of our libraries
    // so we make the test type "release" which will choose the release version of all the
    // modules
    // However, I get a signing error when Android has run a test apk built with the release
    // build type. So, by inheriting the debug buildType into the release configuration, we
    // end up with:
    //
    // 1. release versions of all our library code
    // 2. debug version of the testing code with debug apk packaging.
    //
    // This runs successfully on the devices.
    testBuildType "release"
    buildTypes {
        release {
            initWith debug
        }
    }
}
```